# Correctly parsing my container logs in bluemix Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, containers, logstash, ibm-cloud, kibana

I am using containers in bluemix and I am forwarding my custom application logs to Kibana by just mentioning my log path in environment variable. Now I am able to see my logs in Bluemix Kibana dashboard.

But the problem is that it is not parsing my logs and all the information in my custom log is shown in message field. I want to see different information in different columns so that I can do all the filtering and searching e.g. I want module name, log level, timestamp etc to be picked from my custom log. Right now these fields are coming empty in Kibana and whole line is shown in message field.

Now what are my options? Is it mandatory to start logstash agent in every container instance or do I just need to mention my log patterns somewhere? Is there any other option as well?

Any good links and information would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IBM Bluemix Container Service you could not add custom filters to the existing log service/crawler see [Monitoring and logging IBM Bluemix Container Service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/monitoringandlogging/container_ml_ov.html)

To make logs more meaningful in the Kibana Dashboard you could log JSON formatted Output, which allows better filtering with the IBM Container Service, which is described here [Test Driving Built-in Monitoring and Logging in IBM Containers](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/11/built-in-monitoring-and-logging-for-bluemix-containers/)

*"The net result of this is that, if your app emits JSON formatted logs, they will be properly parsed and indexed in Elastic Search, which can then be queried."*

If that its not enough you need to add your logstash loggers inside your Containers described here [Sending logs to Bluemix using Logstash agent](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/12/sending-logs-to-bluemix-using-logstash-agent/)

Finally you could also deploy your own ELK stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logstash but as you have mentioned that you have multiple containers it will not be advised to install logstash agent on all the containers and then send data to a central server hosting Elasticsearch & Kibana.

You can use the following tools:-

- Use Filebeat (Install it on all the containers) - It is a lightweight data shipper
- Send Filebeat data to Logstash (Central Server which will host Elasticsearch & Kibana)
- Create Logstash Configuration file to parse data & send output to Elasticsearch. (This will be utilising the grok filter of Logstash to parse/process the data into fields).
- Use Kibana to visualise data from Elasticsearch Index.

Comment: But I am using bluemix services which already provide their own ela stic server and kibana dashboard. So, I don't need to have these in my own setup. But probably I will need filebeat and logstash of my own.

Comment: One more question.. The only way that my logs are parsed correctly and broken down to separate fields is only possible if i use logstash and use its filters? Or is there any way that I can specify this fields information in elastic search or Kibana?

Comment: As far as I know you would require using Logstash to parse your data and  using grok filter mapping data into equivalent fields.
It cannot be done at ElasticSearch or Kibana level.